# On my C# program the code for my exe build button has the following bellow but for some reason i get error CS618, How can i fix this?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, builder, codedom, system-codedom-compiler

```cs
private void BuildBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Compile Button

    // .net framework dependency version
            
    ICodeCompiler codeCompiler = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {
            "CompilerVersion",
            "v4.0"
        }
    }).CreateCompiler();
   
    string output = "output.exe";

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ExeNameTB.Text))
    {
        output = ExeNameTB.Text + ".exe";
    }
```

Error says:

> Warning    CS0618  'CodeDomProvider.CreateCompiler()' is obsolete: 'Callers should not use the ICodeCompiler interface and should instead use the methods directly on the CodeDomProvider class. Those inheriting from CodeDomProvider must still implement this interface, and should exclude this warning or also obsolete this method.' rede builder    C:\Users\hugo\Desktop\rede builder\UI\MainUI.cs   281 Active"

Comment: I think the solution is `var provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");` (also I haven't tested it).